# Uploading File from Custom Form HTML

Tags: php, html, upload

I'm trying to upload a file from my custom HTML form to a PHP script. Here is the code that I have in my HTML.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="txt" class="button" type = "text" value = "Choose File" onclick       ="javascript:document.getElementById('file').click();">
    <input id = "file" type="file" style='visibility: hidden;' name="img"    onchange="ChangeText(this, 'txt');"/>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the test.php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

$target = "i/";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
     echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['img']['name']) . "has been uploaded";
}
```

Here's the error on the page:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in /var/www/BLOCKED/test.php on line 7
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpNxxB72' to 'i/' in /var/www/BLOCKED/test.php on line 7.
> Yes it's permissions of the directory are 777.

Comment: "*`The second argument to copy() function cannot be a director...`*" - `copy()`? That function isn't in your posted code; show your full code.

Comment: That is my completely full code. http://uplr.pw/VhZB.png

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: PHP 5. I just installed everything on my VPS yesterday.

Comment: Ok. Well, check the answers below; take your pick. Read the manual also http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

the 2nd argument of move_uploaded_file should be a file name (with path) not a directory

```
$target = "i/".basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
```

Comment: Thanks. I cant believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. The 2nd parameter to `move_uploaded_file()` is not a directory, it should be a file. You just need to append the file's name to `$target` in the 2nd parameter. For example:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target.$_FILES['img']['name'])) {
    echo "The file " . basename($_FILES['img']['name']) . "has been uploaded";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

move_uploaded_file function should be like this:

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $target. $_FILES["img"]["name"])`

add file name at end, as $target is a directory/folder only.

Answer (score 0):

Tantibus, as you can read here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

You must specify the file name to your target file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$target = "i/".basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
```

you probably missed this.